# How can I run a piece of code in background?

Tags: linux, shell-script, background-process

Can I run a piece of code in background instead of using another script?

```
[sesiv@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ cat ./testback2
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)

for i in {1..5}
do
./testscript &
done
wait

        finish_time=$(date +%s)
        seconds=$((finish_time - start_time))
        hours=$((seconds / 3600))
        seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
        minutes=$((seconds / 60))
        seconds=$((seconds % 60))
        echo "Time Taken :"
        echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"

[sesiv@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ ./testback2
sleeping 22436
sleeping 22438
sleeping 22440
sleeping 22442
sleeping 22435
Time Taken :
0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 3 second(s)
```

I tried something like below, but it gives the parent process id. I was expecting 5 different child process ids like above. But the timing here is 3 seconds only.

```
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)
fun() {
echo "$1 $$"
sleep 3
}


for i in {1..5}
do
fun sleeping &
done
wait

        finish_time=$(date +%s)
        seconds=$((finish_time - start_time))
        hours=$((seconds / 3600))
        seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
        minutes=$((seconds / 60))
        seconds=$((seconds % 60))
        echo "Time Taken :"
        echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"

output :
sleeping 22028
sleeping 22028
sleeping 22028
sleeping 22028
sleeping 22028
Time Taken :
0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 3 second(s)
```

NOTE:this is the `testscript` code

```
#!/bin/bash
fun() {
echo "$1 $$"
sleep 3
}

fun sleeping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some occasions when bash creates a new process, but the old value of `$$` is kept. Try `$BASHPID` instead.

Comment: BASHPID doesn't give me anything `[sesiv@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$      echo "BASHPID=$BASHPID" BASHPID=`

Comment: Do you use bash as an interactive shell, or something else? If yes, which version? (Type `bash --version` to find out.) `$BASHPID` was introduced in bash-4.0

Comment: `[user@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ bash --version GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: OK, then $BASHPID doesn't work. But anyhow, if you execute something in the background, then you necessarily create a child process. The `$$` variable does not always reflect that, simply because most of the time it's more convenient for a programmer if every `$$` in a shell script yields the same value.

Comment: can this emulate bash pid `[aehj@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ cut -d " " -f 4 /proc/self/stat
25149
` as mentioned [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.bash/browse_thread/thread/eba0850f18fcb376/e4477b06fd1e7dc8?lnk=raot)

Comment: I don't know; never tried it.

Comment: i tried it now and it seems to work but i dont understand much about `/proc/self/stat` ? i mean what it does. i am just getting the expected output see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but you can use a subshell:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
 ( # bash code
 ) &
done
```

The bash code inside the `()` will be in the same script, but running in a subshell

Answer (score 1):

`$$` is the PID of the original shell process that's running the script. It is not the PID of the shell process that's doing the expansion. `$$` does not change in a subshell.

If you need the PID of the subshell, a portable method is to run `sh -c 'echo $PPID'`. In bash ≥4, the PID of the shell process doing the expansion is in the `BASHPID` magic variable.

```
fun() {
  if [ -n "$BASHPID" ]; then
    echo "$1 $BASHPID"
  else
    echo "$1 $(sh -c 'echo $PPID')"
  fi
  sleep 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i am right but i did this to emulate bashpid for bash 3x and surprisingly results were good :

```
[aehj@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ cat t
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)
fun() {
bashpid=`cut -d " " -f 4 /proc/self/stat`
echo "$1 $bashpid"
sleep 3
}

echo $$
for i in {1..5}
do
fun sleeping &
done
wait

        finish_time=$(date +%s)
        seconds=$((finish_time - start_time))
        hours=$((seconds / 3600))
        seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
        minutes=$((seconds / 60))
        seconds=$((seconds % 60))
        echo "Time Taken :"
        echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"
[aehj@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ ./t
25578
sleeping 25580
sleeping 25583
sleeping 25586
sleeping 25589
sleeping 25592
Time Taken :
0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 3 second(s)
```

another way :

```
[aehj@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ cat u
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)

echo $$
for i in {1..5}
do
{
        fun() {
        BASHPID=`cut -d " " -f 4 /proc/self/stat`
        echo "$1 $BASHPID"
        sleep 3
        }
        fun sleeping
} &

done
wait

        finish_time=$(date +%s)
        seconds=$((finish_time - start_time))
        hours=$((seconds / 3600))
        seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
        minutes=$((seconds / 60))
        seconds=$((seconds % 60))
        echo "Time Taken :"
        echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"
[aehj@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ ./u
25635
sleeping 25637
sleeping 25640
sleeping 25643
sleeping 25646
sleeping 25648
Time Taken :
0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 4 second(s)
```